# Gulp. Массив с путями в отдельном файле, как импортировать

Tags: gulp

```js
const JS = [
 'libs/plugins-scroll/plugins-scroll.min.js',
 'libs/modernizr/modernizr.min.js',
 'libs/superfish/dist/js/superfish.min.js',

 'js/common.js',
]

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
 return gulp.src(JS)
 .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
 .pipe(uglify()) // Mifify js (opt.)
 .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});
```

Могу ли я часть массива вынести в отдельный файл, например что то типа такого как ниже и как правильно написать с учетом синтаксиса js

```js
const JS = [
 require("./libs.config")

 'js/common.js',
]
```

Comment: Возможно, если Вы уточните чего вы хотите добиться таким образом, Вам смогут подсказать другое решение. Так же, возможно, стоит добавить тег `JavaScript` к вопросу, т.к. ваш вопрос больше относится именно к JavaScript. Если вы уже нешли решение данного вопроса, вы можете написать собственный ответ - это может помочь другим пользователям столкнувшимся с подобной проблемой.